# "on" or "at" when talking about flight dates

Tags: prepositions, british-english, dates

I originally had text on a web site that stated:

> Showing flight results for flights from LON to NYC leaving at
>   01/06/2015 and returning at 08/06/2015

One of the testers has said that this should actually be:

> Showing flight results for flights from LON to NYC leaving **on**
>   01/06/2015 and returning **on** 08/06/2015

which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the first result for googling "grammar in vs on for dates": http://5minuteenglish.com/mar18.htm

You use **on** for dates. You use **at** for times. You would use **in** for months or years.

So in your case, the tester is correct.

"I am leaving **on** March 25, 2015."

"I am leaving **at** 12:00."

"I am coming back **in** April."

Answer (score 4):

We use the pronoun *on* when saying that something happens on individual days:

- on Monday
- on 4th January
- on Independence day
- on her birthday
- on Valentine's day
- on that day

We also use *at* for points of time in the day:

- at 5 pm
- at midnight
- at noon
- at dawn
- at lunchtime
- at zero hundred hours

The original poster need *on* here, because the given time is a day:

- **on** 01/06/2015